# Строка считается из файла только частично

Tags: delphi

Читаю из файла t:text строки в переменную st:string. Делаю это в цикле, в какой-то момент времени строка считывается не полностью и в дальнейшем по алгоритму в ней необходимо найти число и вытащить его . Строка такого вида 12346.папапа. Файл создан с помощью rewrite (t, ‘input.txt).
Следовательно кодировка по умолчанию(если скажете какая буду благодарен))) . Я теряю первую часть строки до неопределенного символа . 
Строки состоят только. Из числа точки и кириллицы . Использую Delphi 7.

Comment: Ошибка в программе.

Comment: Дополните вопрос минимальным воспроизводимым примером, т.е. примером кода, входного файла, местом где вы получаете не тот результат, результат который вы получаете и ожидаемым результатом. Пример кода при этом должен быть минимальным, т.е. не содержать не относящихся к проблеме участков.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0):

Проще считывать в `TStringList` методом `LoadFromFile`.
Потом можно ко всему тексту обратиться по `StringListName.text` или к отдельной строке по индексу`[]`.

Comment: TStringList неудобно использовать, когда файл больше гигабайта.